# Python installation in OSX not updating

Tags: macos, python

I've recently got into Python programming and so downloaded the latest version (3.2.3) to install on my Mac running Snow Leopard. I used the installer package. I have run the shell profile update script, but Terminal is still using 2.6.1 to run my programs.

I have tried changing the paths with `sudo nano` as per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/304220/how-can-i-update-the-default-python-installation-fix-my-path-on-mac-os-x-10-6-7) but it makes no difference - it still uses 2.6.1

Any ideas, oh mighty Super Users? I am a complete noob when it comes to Terminal commands.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the commands `echo $PATH` and `which python`, as well as the path to the `python` binary for the copy of Python that you just installed.

Comment: I'm w/@Spiff - if you can show us those two commands he mentions (type them one at a time and then hit enter) we should be able to help!